# Wildcard string search

Tags: python, string

I have a piece of code that is trying to insert `'i'` into an f-string during a for loop. However, I want Python to filter this out based on whether `'i'` contains a certain string (`'nogood'`). I noticed it works with '=' or 'in' but NOT 'like'. I've tried the following but it doesn't compile...

```py
i_list = ['hello', 'good', 'bad', 'bye', 'yup', 'yupnogood', 'hellogood']
final_list = [f"{i}_hello" for i in temp_list if i like '%good%']
```

Do you know if there is a shorthand way to get the wildcard search implemented in there (if it is good practice to do so)?

Comment: There is no *like* operator in Python

Comment: looks like you want to find if it matches a regex pattern

Comment: `if 'nogood' in i` should work - but there is no such string in your `i_list` so this makes no sense. Explain better: [ask] and [edit].

Comment: @PatrickArtner - my code didn't work initially so I was just trying to upload an example data set quickly just for examples sake. My apologies. Just fixed the question so it makes sense

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple form of wildcard search, you can use the `in` operator:

```py
i_list = ['hello', 'good', 'bad', 'bye', 'yup', 'yupnogood', 'hellogood']
final_list = [f"{i}_hello" for i in temp_list if 'nogood' in i]
```

If you want something more complex, you could look into regular expressions.

Comment: thank you so much. marked.